# Odd joke about Monorchid in Elizabeth Finch by Julian Barnes

Tags: meaning, elizabeth-finch, julian-barnes

Here, in the following context from *Elizabeth Finch* by Julian Barnes, E.F. is talking about "Mono"s, The last bolded sentence about "**monorchid**" seems to be an odd joke, but I don't get it. Because there are a lot of states that inspire compassion and to which one cannot aspire.

> 'Monotheism,’ said Elizabeth Finch. ‘Monomania. Monogamy. Monotony.
> Nothing good begins this way.’ She paused. ‘Monogram – a sign of
> vanity. Monocle ditto. Monoculture – a precursor to the death of rural
> Europe. I am prepared to acknowledge the usefulness of a monorail.
> There are many neutral scientific terms which I am also prepared to
> admit. But where the prefix applies to human business … Monoglot, the
> sign of an enclosed and self-deluding country. The monokini, as
> facetious an etymology as it is a garment. Monopoly – and I do not
> refer to the board game – always a disaster if you give it time.
> **Monorchid: a condition to be pitied but not aspired to**'.

Comment: The board game is also a disaster, by the way. It was specifically designed to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [monorchid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monorchid) is simply someone who has only one testicle. This may be a consequence of treatment for testicular cancer, which is not something men "aspire to".